# how to combine multiple objects into one in java?

Tags: java, jackson

I am coming to an issue, where I want to combine multiple objects into one array list object (like my schema) below. Does anyone know how to make it like my schema with my code below? thank you for your help. Much Appreciated. 
PS: Let me know if you want to see my project code in order to understand my problem well.

(This is the way I want it)

```
{

 "hourly": [
    String , 
],
"weekly": [
    String  ,
"yearly": [
    String,  
],
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at whit OBJECTS

ArrayList listaDocentes = new ArrayList();

```
            while (rs.next()) {
                Pedido docen = new Pedido(); --> you need create a new object every time when you need add it at your list.
                docen.setNced(rs.getString(1));
                docen.setNombresDocente(rs.getString(2));
                docen.setRelacionActual(rs.getString(3));
                listaDocentes.add(docen);
            }
```

Comment: will this goes inside my switch statement? under ` case "Range":`?

Comment: This is a obejct create a class DTO
"id":               String, 
"label":            String, 
"pay_grade_description_link":    String,
"job_type":         String,  
"mou":              String,
"mou_description":  String,
"special_notes":    String,
"salary_range_min_step_message": String,

This is a 2d Object in class DTO

"hourly": [
    String , 
],

This is a 3d Object in class DTO

"biweekly": [
    String  ,

This is a 4d Object in class DTO

"annual": [
    String,  
],
Create a DTOwhit your 3 dto
and create your List<NEWOBJECT> and add yout object to this list

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend another approach. Create DTO's (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to represent your response. Then you just have to populate the DTO fields and send It to jackson or GSON to be serialized.

This avoids manually wiring each field and a lot of code that jackson/GSON already do. Also, It separates program logic, serialization logic, and POJO mapping.

Here are some examples of parsing POJO to jackson:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Do you understand my problem? What I want to accomplish? You know how many I tried the link above that you just shared. Can you please show me a working code by parsing the POJO to jackson with my code above? Thanks!