# How to return three objects into one object in java?

Tags: json

I am coming to an issue where I am trying to show one object to look like my schema below. As of now, my json is returning three objects instead of returning one object.  Thank you for you kind help.

```
"hour": [
        String, 
    ],
    "week": [
        String  
    ],
    "year": [
        String,  
    ],
```

Comment: An Array/Collection of the objects? They seem to all be the same object

Comment: yes. The schema is the way I want to return my json objects.

Comment: So what's the issue? Seems like your schema is fine

Comment: You have literally posted this about 3 times a day for the last 2 weeks and deleting it when no one answers. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56809625/how-to-combine-multiple-objects-into-one-in-java)  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897937/how-to-show-one-object-rather-than-three-object-in-java)  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894112/combine-rows-property-in-java)  [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854268/how-to-combine-rows-properly) etc.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options:

1) Return a list with these 3 objects, as you showed
Example:

```
[objA, objB, objC]
```

2) Create a parent (wrapper) object which have a field that is a list

Example:

```
{items: [objA, objB, objC]}
```

Comment: Should I implement in my `Serializer` class, or in my Services code?

Comment: this does not answer to my issue though?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you Schema is complete. Based on what you posted, it seems wrong.

```
{
"id":               "String", 
"label":            "String",
"pay_grade_description_link":    "String",
 "mou":              "String",
"mou_description":  "String",



"rate-type" : {
                "hourly": [
                  "String" 
                ],
                "biweekly": [
                  "String" 
                  ],
                "annual": [
                  "String" 
                ]
              }
}
```

Comment: No, this is the way I want to return. The json I am returning is as of now.  The `rate_type` into one json object as shown in my schema,

Comment: Hey @Aditya do you understand my schema, now?

Comment: I was just pointing out that your schema does not have a ending bracket. If that was intentional then I have no clue how this work.

Comment: So, you see my My Json Result, right? It is printing 3 objects, right?  Instead return 3 objects I want my json result to return as one object like the `rate_type` in my schema where it is return `hourly": [String], "biweekly":[ String], .... ` do you have a clue now?

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what I am saying. I am saying that your schema is not syntactically correct. You start a JSON with a { your need to end it with a }

Comment: Right. But, I am trying to point in my schema how I need help to return as my json object.

Comment: please see This is how I want to return as my json result: code above

Comment: This did not solve it though. Schema is just a prototype how I want my json object to be return.  Am I going to change a code inside my `Serializer`?

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/ make sure your schema compiles on here, you may need to put quotes around the strings.